# In Solidity, trigger function and send ether at the same time

Tags: solidity, contract-development

```
function triggerThisFunction(uint256 addValue) public override payable {
        imaGlobalVariable += msg.value;
        imAlsoaGlobal += addValue;
    }
```

Utilizing strictly solidity, how do I trigger this function and send it ether at the same time from another contract?

So far,

```
function letsGoTrigger() public {
       implement = constructorOfImplement(targetAddress);
        return implement.triggerThisFunction(1);
    }
```

But what comes after triggerThisFunction(1)?

Is it... .value()? I'm totally unaware of what to put here.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like

```
implement.triggerThisFunction{value: 10, gas: 800}(1);
```

and you can get details from https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/control-structures.html?highlight=contract%20%20%20%20instance#external-function-calls